# Java static constructor access in child class

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, static, protected

I have two classes

```
package a;

public class A {

  protected void doSomething() {

  }

  protected static class C {
    protected C(int c) {
    }
  }
}

package b;

public class B extends A {

  @Override
  protected void doSomething() {
    C c = new C(0); //compile error
    C c2 = new C(0){}; //legal
  }
}
```

I have read chapter 6.6.2.2. Access to a protected Constructor of JLS (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html) but i am still confused with the explanation. What is wrong with the call of the super constructor `new C(0);` even if B is a child of A?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variables, methods, and constructors, which are declared protected in a superclass can be accessed only by the subclasses in other package or any class within the package of the protected members' class.

Now, the constructor of `C` class is protected therefore is accessible outside the `a` package only by subclasses of `C`. But `B` is not a subclass of `C` ...

As @Amongalen pointed out, the second statement

```
C c2 = new C(0){};
```

is legal because it creates an anonymous class that extends `C`, therefore the protected constructor is visible here.

Comment: `C c2 = new C(0){};` - this works because it creates an anonymous class implementing `C`, am I right?

Comment: @Amongalen Right, actually it extends `C`